# Difference between define and simple variable in PHP

Tags: php

What is the difference and/or benefit of using define. for example in db file i can define password or any variable that i am going to use throughout website like this:

```
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
```

Instead of above code, I can also use it in db file like this:

```
$DB_PASSWORD="mypassword";
```

Both will serve same purpose...
db file will be included in every page of website. So is there any benefit of using define rather then just declaring a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Define** defines a value, a constant which you can not change while variable means it's value may or will vary.

**EDIT:**
Both have practical usage. There are sometimes data which should not be changed or it is always the same. For example a hex code of color blue will always be `0000FF` or a database password may never be changed while the session is running.

It's more of a security tool than a performance or readability concern. Once you `DEFINE`, there's no way back, but you're sure your data is the same across the whole instance.

Answer (score 3):

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'); cleated and defines a GLOBAL CONSTANT that cannot changed (well not easily) and when you call it you will not need the "$" sign.

Answer (score 2):

For data that you do not intend to change throughout your script (static data such as a database password) you should define it.  If you will ever re-assign it a new value, use a variable.